# How do I add a comma as my delimiter for the output of awk

Tags: awk

How do I add a comma as my delimiter for the output of awk

```
> cat file.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
col1,col2,col3
col1,col2
col1
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

This is my attempt:

```
> awk -F, 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1 $2}' file.csv
    col1col2
    col1col2
    col1col2
    col1
    col1col2
    >
```

What I want is this

```
col1,col2
col1,col2
col1,col2
col1,
col1,col2
```

### Below is just for my ref:

```
> awk -F, '{print $0}' file.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
col1,col2,col3
col1,col2
col1
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5

> awk -F, '{print $1}' file.csv
col1
col1
col1
col1
col1

> awk -F, '{print $1 $2}' file.csv
col1col2
col1col2
col1col2
col1
col1col2
```

Comment: `print $1,$2` instead.

Comment: This is a quirk of awk: there is no string concatenation _operator_. Placing two strings side-by-side (discounting the whitespace in between) concatenates the two fields.

Comment: `awk -F, 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1 $2}' file.csv` is redundant, either use `-F,` or set `FS` value in `BEGIN`. If you are not strictly limited to using `awk` you might get this task done using [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) command.

Comment: @Daweo what if my input delimiter is different to my output delimiter e.g. `xyz` below?
should awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS="xyz"} {print $1 $2}' file.csv

Comment: @HattrickNZ you might mix, but for consistency I suggest `awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="xyz"}{print $1,$2}' file.csv`

Answer (score 2):

The statement `print $1 $2` prints *one* output field, the concatenation of `$1` and `$2`. Hence there will be no `OFS` output.

What you're looking for is `print $1, $2` which prints two *distinct* fields, and will therefore have the `OFS` inserted between them. You can see the difference in the following transcript:

```bash
pax@styx:~> echo "1 2" | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="-xyzzy-"}{print $1 $2}'
12
pax@styx:~> echo "1 2" | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="-xyzzy-"}{print $1, $2}'
1-xyzzy-2
```

Answer (score 0):

if you actually want that trailing `","` :

> ```
>  mawk NF=2 FS=, OFS=,
> ```

```
col1,col2
col1,col2
col1,col2
col1,
col1,col2
```

...without the trailing `","` :

> ```
> gawk 'NF < 2 || NF = 2' FS=, OFS=,
> ```

```
col1,col2
col1,col2
col1,col2
col1
col1,col2
```